# Stub or fake an ajax function that does not take a callback as a parameter

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I am trying to create a test for an ajax function in my code base that I can't change which is pretty much like this:

```
function myFetch (src) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: src
  })
}
```

I call it like this and get back an array of json objects (as an example)

```
myFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(i => console.log(i))
```

How would I create a fake XHR or fake server (or other ideas that come to mind) for this? I've only ever seen examples, including the sinon docs that show how to do it with a callback, so if my function was `myFetch(src, callback)` I could use:

```
sinon.replace(jQuery, 'ajax', sinon.fake());
myFetch(fake.com, sinon.fake());
```

Or something like this I assume, since I am not totally sure if this would work.,

But how do I do this since my function does not have a callback, or even a 'success' or anything to stub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` is not callback function but return `Promise`. That's why you use `then` when calling it. For testing `Promise`, sinon has good methods `resolves` and `reject`. So, based on your code, you can do it like this.

```
const fakeResponse = [{ todo_id: 1, todo_name: 'get wake up' }];
sinon.stub(jQuery, 'ajax').resolves(fakeResponse);
getTodos(42);
```

Reference: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/stubs/

Hope it helps

Comment: This helped! I got it to work like this:`let okResponse = [
      {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'status': 200
      } ] let stub = sinon.stub($, 'ajax') let results = myFetch('aFakeURL.com')    return results.then(result => expect(result).to.equal(okResponse))`

Comment: @MoteZart glad to hear that 